# Cannot cat a world readable file: permission denied

Tags: shell, permissions

I want to read the content of a file at a known path in a different user home.
The file is world readable, and so are all the sub directories.

How ever, when I try to open it, I get a "permission denied"

```
cat /home/rails/current/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid
cat: /home/rails/current/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid: Permission denied
```

With

```
rails@tatoo:~/current/tmp/pids$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 rails rails 6 Dec 30 10:09 delayed_job.pid
```

What could I be missing ?

Comment: you have to check that each sub-dir in that path has the correct permissions. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter is right. very likely you cannot access `/home/rails`

Comment: I checked multiples times, and all permissions of every sub dir seemed correct. I added execution and it seemed to do the trick...

Comment: If this _seemed to do the trick_, why don't you accept the answer below, which even refers an explanation?

Answer (score 4):

To be able to read a file, not only you need to have read access to the file `r` but you also need to have access right `x` for every directory in that file path up to the root directory.

As execution right doesn't make sense for a directory, the `x` bit is used to grant access rights for it.

Have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work/21252#21252) for a detailed explanation about directory permissions.